# Trouble executing a string query in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

## Question

i have a stored procedure that executes a string query from a function. but when executing the string i keep getting the error

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> 'UPDATE rm_sensor_combined     SET subid = 0, rmip = '10.7.75.122', dname = 'ESD-' at line 4

## Bellow is the content of the procedure.

> if as_option = "updateData" then 
> SET ls_option := "UPDATE";
> SET ls_query = (select fn_Sys_GenUpdateDetail(as_table, ls_option) );
> end if; 
> SET @sql := ls_query ; 
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
> EXECUTE stmt;

[stored procedure execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8bsf.png)
[here is the result from the function, therefore the query to be executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjC0l.png)

**quoted**

> '  UPDATE rm_sensor_combined \n   SET subid = 0, rmip = '10.7.75.122', dname = 'ESD-001', dlocation = 'FFF-GGG-SS', warning_max = 2000, alert_max = 4000, ispaused = 0, isused = 1, update_by = ''\n  where giruid =1 and rscuid = 1 and (subid = 0 or rmip = '10.7.75.122' or dname = 'ESD-001'  or dlocation = 'FFF-GGG-SS'  or warning_max = 2000 or alert_max = 4000 or ispaused = 0 or isused = 1);  \n   UPDATE rm_sensor_combined \n   SET subid = 0, rmip = '10.7.75.122', dname = 'ESD-002', dlocation = ' - - ', warning_max = 2000, alert_max = 4000, ispaused = 0, isused = 0, update_by = ''\n  where giruid =1 and rscuid = 2 and (subid = 0 or rmip = '10.7.75.122' or dname = 'ESD-002'  or dlocation = ' - - '  or warning_max = 2000 or alert_max = 4000 or ispaused = 0 or isused = 0);  \n '

**Unquoted**

> UPDATE rm_sensor_combined
> SET subid = 0, rmip = '10.7.75.122', dname = 'ESD-001', dlocation = 'FFF-GGG-SS', warning_max = 2000, alert_max = 4000, ispaused = 0, isused = 1, update_by = ''
> where giruid =1 and rscuid = 1 and (subid = 0 or rmip = '10.7.75.122' or dname = 'ESD-001'  or dlocation = 'FFF-GGG-SS'  or warning_max = 2000 or alert_max = 4000 or ispaused = 0 or isused = 1);
> UPDATE rm_sensor_combined
> SET subid = 0, rmip = '10.7.75.122', dname = 'ESD-002', dlocation = ' - - ', warning_max = 2000, alert_max = 4000, ispaused = 0, isused = 0, update_by = ''
> where giruid =1 and rscuid = 2 and (subid = 0 or rmip = '10.7.75.122' or dname = 'ESD-002'  or dlocation = ' - - '  or warning_max = 2000 or alert_max = 4000 or ispaused = 0 or isused = 0);

any help on what is causing the error would help.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html says:

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ; characters).

You need to run your statements one at a time.

Comment: your Answer has been a great help. thank you !